# Downloaded Vertex AI automl model , can't convert to h5 file

Tags: tensorflow, automl

This question is also on main SO.

I saw on meta [it's fine to ask on two forums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVFm2.png)

I downloaded from the bucket my VertexAI AutoML, this is how it looks:

[image]

When I try:

````
```import tensorflow as tf

# Load the saved_model.pb file
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('xxxxxxx/2022-12-04T07:24:02.969877Z/predict/001')

# Save the model in h5 format
model.save('yyyyyyy.h5')```
````

I get the error:

[image]
And when I try

````
```model = tf.saved_model.load('xxxxxxx/2022-12-04T07:24:02.969877Z/predict/001')

# Save the model in h5 format
model.save('model.h5')```
````

I get the error:

[image]

How can I transform the pb file to h5?

[link to so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74675116/downloaded-vertex-ai-automl-model-cant-convert-to-h5-file)

Answer (score 0):

The model is an AutoML tabular model.

Currently there is a [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-model-tabular#aiplatform_export_model_tabular_classification_sample-console):

> The exported tabular model can run only on x86 architecture CPUs that
> support Advanced Vector Extensions (AVX) instruction sets.

Not sure that the errors are related to the cpu, but also if transformed, the needed architecture makes the model irrelevant.